# How to set validation up for multiple specific lengths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am setting up some validation in my model and am curious on how to validate for 3 different specific lenghts?  I want to validate 10, 12 or 13 specifically for the UPC.  I see in the docs how to do it for one specifically.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1024 }, uniqueness: true
  validates :upc, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { is: 10 }, uniqueness: true
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :product_properties
end
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom method

```
validate :check_for_length

def check_for_length
  errors.add(:upc, :wrong_length) unless [10,12,13].include?(upc.length)
end
```

Now in your en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        product:
          attributes:
            upc:
              wrong_length: "your_message"
```

Comment: How about `unless [10,12,13].include?(upc.length)` instead?

Comment: Also, `errors.add(:upc, :wrong_length)` will allow I18n to work and translations can be added for the error.

Comment: One of the reasons, I put the condition was if he wants to play around error messages. @jvillian Like your solution it's clean and precise.

Comment: Or, make it a one-liner: `errors.add(:upc, :wrong_length) unless [10,12,13].include?(upc.length)`. Saves you 27 characters and two lines, FWIW.

Comment: Awesome! These are great!  Thanks so much.